# Vertex minors of paths

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, combinatorial-geometry, algebraic-graph-theory

> **(Vertex Minor)** A graph H is a vertex minor of G if H can be obtained from G by a sequence of vertex deletions and local complementation
>
> (**Local complementation**) A local complementation $\tau_v$ is a graph operation specified by a vertex $v$, taking a graph $G$ to $\tau_v(G)$ by replacing the induced subgraph on the neighborhood of $v$, i.e. $G\left[N_v\right]$, by its complement. The neighborhood of any vertex $u$ in the graph $\tau_v(G)$ is therefore given by
> $$
> N_u^{\left(\tau_v(G)\right)}= \begin{cases}N_u \Delta\left(N_v \backslash\{u\}\right) & \text { if }(u, v) \in E(G), \\ N_u & \text { otherwise.}\end{cases}
> $$

**The question**

What is the minimum $m$ such that $K_n$( complete graph with $n$ vertices) is a vertex-minor of the path graph $P_m$ on $m$ vertices?

**My attempt**

The best I've got so far is $m=2n-3$.

Here's an example.
The path graph with $m=2n-3=7$

[image]

Perform the operations $LC[i+1]\,D[i]\,LC[i]\,LC[i+1]$ in sequence; where $i\in{3,5}$
,$LC[i]$ is local complementation on vertex $i$, $D[i]$ is deletion of vertex $i$. Then we get,

[image]

The complete graph with $n=5$

The operations $LC[i+1]\,D[i]\,LC[i]\,LC[i+1]$ are of special relevance in my field, it corresponds to a certain kind of measurement on a physical system. Thus my protocol is just a set of measurements of the systems corresponding to odd vertices. I was thus hoping that $m=2n-3$ is the minimum since I could then show the optimality of my protocol.

Even if not a proof, I would like to know existing  research in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, $m\ge 2n-3$. To see this, I'll use the concept called the "maximum cut-rank" function of a graph; see Nguyen and Oum [The average cut-rank of graphs, European J. Combinatorics, 90 (2020) 103183].

Let us write $\rho(G)$ to denote the maximum of the cut-rank function $\rho_G(X)$ over all subsets of the vertex set of G.
Clearly, $\rho(K_n)=1$ and $\rho(P_m)=\lfloor  m/2\rfloor$.
(We usually write $P_m$ to denote the path graph on $m$ vertices.)

Now, observe that if $H=G-v$, then $\rho(H)\ge \rho(G)-1$ for the obvious reason; the rank of a matrix cannot decrease by more than 1 if we delete only 1 row.

Since the local complementation does not change the maximum cut-rank, we deduce that if $K_n$ is a vertex-minor of $P_m$, then the number of vertices that have to be removed should be at least $\rho(P_m)-\rho(K_n)$.
Thus $m-\lfloor m/2\rfloor+1 \ge n$.

We deduce that $m-(m-1)/2+1\ge n$, which implies that $m\ge 2n-3$.